# arrays last element that has color never gets accessed

Tags: unity, c#

I have assigned this C# script to a spot light. But the green color which is at 2nd position in array never gets accessed and spot light never gets green light. I tried debugging this code but no idea what's wrong

```
public class CSharping : MonoBehaviour {

    public Light lt;

    Color[] allColor = { Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green}; 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        lt  = GetComponent<Light>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            int colorVariable = Random.Range(0,2);
            lt.color = allColor[colorVariable]; 
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your problem is that when you call `Random.Range(0,2)`, your only getting the output of `0` or `1`. This, to me, sounds like reasonable behavior for the `Random.Range()` method. As has been explained to me, random is tricky for a computer, and the default method is *very* unreliable.

Comment: @Gnemlock Random.Range(0,2)....here 0 and 2 are inclusive according to Unity docs

Comment: @Gnemlock please check my updated question

Comment: I'm actually in the process of answering, and your comment / update confirms it. You want to use `Random.Range(0,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the another overload the Range method in the docs for float variables but using integers.

From Unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html):

> public static float Range(float min, float max);
>
> Returns a random float number between and min [inclusive] and max
> [inclusive] (Read Only).
> Note that max is inclusive, so using Random.Range( 0.0f, 1.0f ) could
> return 1.0 as a value.
>
> public static int Range(int min, int max);
>
> Returns a random integer number between min [inclusive] and max [exclusive] (Read Only).
> Note that max is exclusive, so using Random.Range( 0, 10 ) will return values between 0 and 9.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check the screen shot from Unity Docs

Comment: this fixed the error but documentation is wrong

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan, see my answer. I believe the error is in your interpretation.

Comment: update answer, but @Gnemlock make it first =)

Comment: Seems if I was right, you could have just up voted my answer, instead of copying it. -1

Comment: @Gnemlock I updated my answer before I saw yours.

Answer (score 5):

**You are using `Random.Range(int, int)`, not `Random.Range(float, float)`. In the example you give, the max value is *not* inclusive**.

Let's take a look at [the Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html):

> ### Random.Range
>
> `public static float Range(float min, float max);`
> Returns a random float number between and<sup>[*sic*]</sup> `min` [inclusive] and `max` [inclusive] (Read Only). Note that max is inclusive, so using `Random.Range( 0.0f, 1.0f )` could return 1.0 as a value. 
> **...**
> `public static int Range(int min, int max);`
> Returns a random integer number between `min` [inclusive] and `max` [exclusive] (Read Only). Note that max is exclusive, so using `Random.Range( 0, 10 )` will return values between 0 and 9. If max equals min, min will be returned.
> **<sup>- [Unity API: Random.Range](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)</sup>**

---

Given that your returning an `int`, the method `int Range(int min, int max)` will be called, where `max` is *exclusive*. To return the values `0`, `1` or `2` you should use `Random.Range(0, 3)`.